# Cannot Partition Disk with Disk Utility

Tags: snow-leopard, disk-utility, partition, error

I can't seem to partition my disk with Disk Utility or with the Terminal command (see screenshots).
Something also happened to my other partition running Mavericks, where it just turned into an "empty name" partition, but still runs fine.  Any help would be much appreciated

[image]
[image].

Answer (score 1):

You could try booting into internet recovery (hold Command+Option+R during boot) once there open disk utility and try partitioning again.